# Como determinar cuantas posibles combinaciones hay de 5 caracteres (A,B,C,D,E), PHP

Tags: php, algoritmos

Quiero desarrolla un algoritmo que me permita ver todas las posibles combinaciones de 5 caracteres ejemplo:

```
AEDBC
DBCAE
AAABC
```

ETC ...

```
<?php

//Tengo 5 variables

$a = "A";
$a = "B";
$a = "C";
$a = "D";
$a = "E";

//Ejemplo las primeras combinación serian así:
// 1.- AAAAA
// 2.- AAAAB

//Después:

//BBBBB
//BBBBA

//etc...


?>
```

MOSTRAR UNA LISTA CON TODAS LAS COMBINACIONES POSIBLES

Comment: Agrega por favor que has intentado y que fallos ha presentado el código

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: googlea **combinatoria**

Comment: Cinco bucles anidados, cada bucle itera por las letras ABCDE. El bucle interno concatena las cinco variables usadas en cada bucle, y muestra el resultado. Cuidado, saldrán 3125 líneas al ejecutar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto escribe todas las combinaciones linea a linea y el numero total.

```
<?php

$letras=["A","B","C","D","E"];
$contador=0;

for($i=0;$i<=4; $i++){
        for($j=0; $j<=4;$j++){
                for($k=0;$k<=4;$k++){
                        for($l=0;$l<=4;$l++){
                                for($m=0;$m<=4;$m++){
                                        echo "$letras[$i]$letras[$j]$letras[$k]$letras[$l]$letras[$m] \n";
                                        $contador+=1;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
echo "Combinaciones $contador \n";
?>
```

Comment: me servio mucho tu respuesta, Gracias!